# Como eliminar un diccionario dentro de una lista de diccionarios de un archivo .json

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo users.json que tiene una lista con un diccionario por cada usuario:

```
[
{
    "user_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "email": "facundo@example.com",
    "first_name": "Facundo",
    "last_name": "Garcia",
    "birth_date": "2021-10-28",
    "password": "holasoyfacundo"
},
{
    "user_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa7",
    "email": "miguel@example.com",
    "first_name": "Miguel",
    "last_name": "Torres",
    "birth_date": "2021-10-28",
    "password": "holasoymiguel"
},
{
    "user_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa8",
    "email": "Rocio@example.com",
    "first_name": "Rocio",
    "last_name": "Torres",
    "birth_date": "2021-10-28",
    "password": "holasoyrocio"
},
{
    "user_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa9",
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "first_name": "string",
    "last_name": "string",
    "birth_date": "2021-11-01",
    "password": "stringst"
}
]
```

Y ahora quiero eliminar uno de los usuarios a través de su user_id quitando el diccionario al que pertenece dentro del archivo.
Probé con este código:

```
import json

user_id = "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa9"
with open("copia_users.json", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    results = json.loads(f.read())
    for user in results:
        if user["user_id"] == user_id:
            results.remove(user)
            break
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json.dumps(results))
    print("user removed")
```

pero después de ejecutarlo se me rompe la estructura que tenia en el archivo users.json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema está en la escritura del fichero. Un `seek()` te "rebobina" la cabeza de escritura al inicio del fichero, y a partir de ahí sobreescribes lo que había, pero no truncas el fichero, por lo que lo que hubiera antes "debajo", si era más largo, "asomará". Creo que sería más sencillo cerrar el fichero y volver a abrirlo para escritura antes de volcar la lista. El abrir para escritura sí lo trunca a tamaño cero

Comment: ¿Y que tal si vuelcas el contenido del archivo en memoria, en una variable de tipo lista con sus diccionarios, eliminas el elemento de la lista que deseas y sobreescribes el archivo con el contenido de tu lista?

Comment: Aparte de eso eliminar elementos de una lista mientras la recorres también puede producir resultados inesperados. Es mejor crear otra lista que tenga todos los usuarios, salvo el que quieras eliminar. Por ejemplo: `resultado = [ user for user in results if user["user_id"] != user_id ]`